# M2 backend and front end not working properly

Tags: admin, magento2, installation

I just installed M2 with all sample data. It was installed successfully but admin left panel links are not working. They all seems to be disabled.

My System: 
1) Windows 7
2) Latest xampp (php 5.6.14)

Installation was successful but there is no sample data on front end either except few static page links like 'Privacy Policy' etc.

I guess there might be issue with windows 7 but i am not sure because installation was cool and success. What I am missing here?

> In short it was installed successfully but not working much on frontend and admin as well.

[image: Magento 2 Backend]

[image: Magento 2 Front end]

Added images of front and backend. All links of left panel are not working in admin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this **Before that take Backup**

1. Remove everything, except `.htaccess` file from `pub/static` folder
2. Open up `app/etc/di.xml` find the path `“Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink”` and replace to `Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy`

**Note**: Remove entire files and folder under pub/static except `.htaccess` file.

For More info ref this http://www.dckap.com/blog/magento-2-admin-links-not-working-in-windows/

Comment: You solution work and links are working now. Can you please tell me why i need to do this?
And i downloaded and installed m2 with sample data but there is no product and categories in admin. what can be the reason for this?

Comment: I don't think exactly may me some file permission problem.

Comment: Ok dear. I will take care of it. Big thanks. Voted up your response and accepted

Answer (score 1):

You need run command: `php -f bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` in magento install directory

Comment: I am using window 7 system. Do i also need to run command there?

Comment: You open cmd, next using command cd to folder install magento2, and run above this command.

Comment: I have installed magento in M2 folder (D:\php56\htdocs\mg\M2) and here is link of commands http://prntscr.com/97xyk9  pls check screen shot link which I ran in command prompt. Please guide me what need to do?

Comment: solution of @kothari works and links are working now. Can you please tell me why i need to do this? And i downloaded and installed m2 with sample data but there is no product and categories in admin. what can be the reason for this?

Comment: If there are no categories as shown in your screen capture, you did not install sample data correctly.